# How to use an existing business layer with new .net single page application

Tags: single-page-application

I have an existing application we are converting to use Single Page Application technology.  My business layer returns arrays and lists for the most part.  Question is, how do i get a SPA app to use the existing business layer?

Most of what i see for examples use Entitiy Frameworks.  I need to use my business layer, and not create EF.

Any examples or ideas?  I am using the hot towel template by John Papa for my SPA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create web services that expose the arrays, or use the ones you have. Ideally, they would return JSON.

then you can create the client anyway you like, and have it talk to the server via those services .

if you want breeze, then you could create a dummy project, load in the poco models to EF, then hook breeze's controller to it. Grab the metadata, then copy that metadata to your real web services and return it from there. That way you can use breeze very well on your client. breeze has docs on this too

Comment: My business layer is a class library that i would rather communicate directly from my spa/mvc web project if possible, without web services.  The problem is getting url's for a web service in a large corporate environment is a project in itself.  I can format the arrays in my business layer as JSON. Is it possible to do it without web services? How?

Comment: You could use MVC controllers to return ActionResults as JSON. But that's just a harder way to make Web API. But you can do it.

Comment: You also could embed the JSON in the HTML when you render the page. But I personally don't like that. I don;t think I can help you much here as I would go web services.

Comment: Thanks John.  Looking into see if I have enough time to get Web Service before our deadlines.  Appreciate the answers sir!